# How to limit the FTP bandwidth for one user?

Tags: vps, ftp, bandwidth, performance

I have no experience in webmastering, so sorry if it is a simple question!

I have a VPS and about 30GB files on it and I am trying to download them to my PC. So for transfering them I made an FTP.

But when I download it, the speed is too low. How can I set the whole bandwidth for one user (myself) to access the maximum speed?

(The server OS is Windows Server 2003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since this is quite a mystery, the first step to getting better bandwidth is finding out exactly **where** the bottleneck is. Using [Network-Tools.com](http://network-tools.com/), you can Trace Route and find out what is causing the problem.

If the bottleneck is around your ISP or earlier, then there isn't anything you can do about it. If it is at your server, then look at closing simultaneous connections to 1, and close your anonymous FTP access, close all ports that aren't **actively** being used, etc.

Speed is something of an art, if anything. There isn't one setting or an add-on, there are simply too many variables for it to be that easy. You can use several techniques to increase server speed, but a fix-all solution isn't available.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that you may find goes faster overnight when Internet traffic is lower. This *should* make your data transfer speeds faster then during the especially during peak hours. If the bottleneck is your own Internet connection then opening up multiple connections probably won't help you as downloading multiple files as once just splits the available bandwidth among them.

Comment: At the same time when I download another file the speed is very much faster. But with my FTP is too low. So you mean there is nothing I can do at the other side, server side?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the main limitation on download speed is the speed of your own internet connection.

The only other thing you can do is change the number of simultaneous connections the FTP client can make (this is done in the FTP software itself).

Comment: When I download a file from another site, the speed is fine, it is great. but just with my FTP.